# Disable greeting message from spatialite cmdline

Tags: spatialite

I can emit plain values in SQLite3:

```
$ echo 'select 1;' | sqlite3
1
```

However, SpatiaLite always emits a greeting:

```
$ echo 'select asgeojson(st_point(1,2));' | spatialite
SpatiaLite version ..: 5.0.0    Supported Extensions:
        - 'VirtualShape'        [direct Shapefile access]
        - 'VirtualDbf'          [direct DBF access]
        - 'VirtualText'         [direct CSV/TXT access]
        - 'VirtualGeoJSON'              [direct GeoJSON access]
        - 'VirtualXL'           [direct XLS access]
        - 'VirtualNetwork'      [Dijkstra shortest path - obsolete]
        - 'RTree'               [Spatial Index - R*Tree]
        - 'MbrCache'            [Spatial Index - MBR cache]
        - 'VirtualFDO'          [FDO-OGR interoperability]
        - 'VirtualBBox'         [BoundingBox tables]
        - 'VirtualSpatialIndex' [R*Tree metahandler]
        - 'VirtualElementary'   [ElemGeoms metahandler]
        - 'VirtualRouting'      [Dijkstra shortest path - advanced]
        - 'VirtualKNN'  [K-Nearest Neighbors metahandler]
        - 'VirtualGPKG' [OGC GeoPackage interoperability]
        - 'SpatiaLite'          [Spatial SQL - OGC]
        - 'VirtualXPath'        [XML Path Language - XPath]
PROJ version ........: Rel. 7.2.0, November 1st, 2020
GEOS version ........: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
RTTOPO version ......: 1.1.0
TARGET CPU ..........: x86_64-linux-gnu
the SPATIAL_REF_SYS table already contains some row(s)
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[1,2]}
$
```

Both the greeting and my desired GeoJSON are going to stdout:

```
$ echo 'select asgeojson(st_point(1,2));' | spatialite >/dev/null
the SPATIAL_REF_SYS table already contains some row(s)
$
```

How can I run `spatialite` command-line tool and get it to emit only the stuff that I need (in this example, the GeoJSON)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the help screen.

```
spatialite -help
Usage: spatialite [OPTIONS] FILENAME [SQL]
FILENAME is the name of an SQLite database. A new database is created
if the file does not previously exist.
OPTIONS include:
   -bail                stop after hitting an error
   -batch               force batch I/O
   -column              set output mode to 'column'
   -cmd command         run "command" before reading stdin
   -csv                 set output mode to 'csv'
   -echo                print commands before execution
   -init filename       read/process named file
   -[no]header          turn headers on or off
   -help                show this message
   -html                set output mode to HTML
   -interactive         force interactive I/O
   -line                set output mode to 'line'
   -list                set output mode to 'list'
   -silent              suppress the welcome message
   -nullvalue 'text'    set text string for NULL values
   -separator 'x'       set output field separator (|)
   -stats               print memory stats before each finalize
   -version             show SQLite version
   -vfs NAME            use NAME as the default VFS
```

Option **-silent** looks promising.

It almost works on Windows like this:

```
echo select asgeojson(st_point(1,2)); |spatialite -silent
        - 'VirtualXPath'        [XML Path Language - XPath]
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[1,2]}
```

Please file a bug report into the SpatiaLite Fossil repository about the VirtualXPath that cannot be silenced.

Comment: Thanks! Re. bug report -- I built spatialite from source (spatialite-tools b204bdfa8232383b4c36837443f4f5c5dc1b248f, libspatialite c2c4ea9179b6cda7e7aa6fd5e8a29c9108911762) and it doesn't emit the VirtualXPath message any more.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it has been fixed by https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/info/760ef1affb822806 and some older ticket.